# Bulk Delete and Update Events on Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to reflect Zoom schedules from 32 Zoom accounts on Google Calendar. I have shared 32 Calendar to 1 Master Calendar. I will get Scheduled Meetings through API and create Google Calendar Events.

```js
function createEvent() {
  var lstMeetings = getMeetings(); //Creating Zoom Meetings list
  var lstAcc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1].getRange(2, 1, 32, 4).getValues(); //Getting Calendar ID
  var calendar, events_delete;
  var now = new Date();
  var end = new Date(now.getTime() + (180 * 24 * 60 * 60000));
  var temp;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < lstAcc.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(lstMeetings[i].length);
    for (var j = 0; j < lstMeetings[i].length; j++) {
      var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(lstAcc[i][0]).createEvent(
        lstMeetings[i][j].topic,
        new Date(lstMeetings[i][j].start_time),
        new Date(lstMeetings[i][j].end_time),
        {description: lstMeetings[i][j].description}
      );
      Logger.log(events.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running into `You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later.` error.

Addition to the code, I would like to bulk delete all events and create new events reflect to the schedule on Zoom. How can I achieve that?

I'm thinking to switch to Webhook so that it would be easier to handle, but I'm not sure how to do that yet.

If you have any advice, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later.

Means exactly that you have been doing to much.  This is a free api there are limits to the number of creates and deletes you can make over a period of time.   This limit is to my knowledge undocumented.  I would start with one a minute and work your way up and down until you find the limits.

This is the closes thing i have found [Avoid calendar use limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en)  It doesnt say how many are allowed per minute or per hour.